# Adding new column to a dynamically created table in PHP which has specific query

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and MySQL.

This a project for a travel agency.
there is form to insert details of a vehicle into database 
 including current date and time. And details can be inserted multiple times for a vehicle in a day.

Now I am dynamically creating a table in HTML to display details of vehicle from database.

Now I have to add a new column to above html table to show the count of particular vehicle inserted for current day.
How to query it in sql;

Comment: what exactly is your question? and add here what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please be clear in your Question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/378/add-a-column-to-an-existing-mysql-table/ this might be what you're looking for. Try google next time :)

Comment: what is that table you are talking about? HTML table or DB table?

Comment: I am sorry for incomplete question. I have edited the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this in your HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>Count</td>
  <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
</tr>
```

In MySql,

```
SELECT COUNT(vehicle_name) FROM myTable WHERE DATE(myDate) = DATE(NOW());
```

Comment: Please consider adding more detail to your answer. Why does this work, what are some potential drawbacks of this approach, etc.

Comment: I am sorry for incomplete question. I have edited the question now

Comment: @Vivek Its kind of correct vivek. Your answer was helpful. Thank you.